# Error repairing Exchange 2016 install on Windows 10

Tags: exchange, powershell, windows-10, exchange-2016

I am trying to install Exchange 2016 CU6 on my Windows 10 machine (management tools only), but when I run the CU6 installer, nothing happens at all (splash screen appears, then disappears and no further dialogues or error messages).

When I went to repair my CU1 installation, it says it has detected an incomplete installation and needs to try and complete it. After attempting to do so, it fails with this error:

```
Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
          $roleList = $RoleRoles.Replace('Role','').Split(',');

          if($roleList -contains 'LanguagePacks')
          {
            & $RoleBinPath\ServiceControl.ps1 Save
            & $RoleBinPath\ServiceControl.ps1 DisableServices $roleList;
            & $RoleBinPath\ServiceControl.ps1 Stop $roleList;

          };
        " was run: "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceCommandException: 
        Service 'Application Identity (AppIDSvc)' cannot be configured due to the 
        following error: Access is denied ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 
        Access is denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---".
```

Can anyone advise how I go about repairing this install, so that I can either fully remove it and start over, or try the CU6 installer again to complete the update?

I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/afb79729-08da-4521-91a0-6e8789c550e6/unable-to-update-admin-tools-to-exchange-2013-cu-10-on-windows-10-machine?forum=exchangesvrdeploy) link where someone edits one of the install scripts to exclude the AppIDSvc which allowed them to continue with a 2013 install, but that obviously shouldn't be something you do. I am hoping there may be a clean supported way around this.

Comment: what windows 10 build?

Comment: 1703, 15063.608

Comment: may be you can remove it using revo.. third-party tool . uninstall all excahange and related traces from windows 10. make sure to create a restore point before proceed . free version is enough .. https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html

Comment: by the way, i feel you cu6 installer might be corrupted. so its wise to redownload a fresh copy and retry or just verify hash values in downloaded file

Comment: I ended up tweaking the powershell scripts to get around this, as well as clearing out all traces of the previous pending installation. Once I did that, I was able to repair the CU1 install, and then update to CU6 using the CLI (GUI for some reason did not work).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up tweaking the powershell scripts to get around this, as well as clearing out all traces of the previous pending installation. Once I did that, I was able to repair the CU1 install, and then update to CU6 using the CLI (GUI for some reason did not work).